# redirect to index using staticApp with defaultWebAppSettings

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-wai

I'm using the wai-app-static static package to serve a small website. Originally I called it as:

```
staticApp defaultFileServerSettings root
```

and all was right with the world. I wanted to switch to using defaultWebAppSettings, though, (as this is a website). I was able to get that to work, such that if I went to `http://localhost:3000/index.html`, it was fine, but I also need to set up a redirect from the root folder to the index site (viz. `http://localhost:3000 --> http://localhost:3000/index.html`).

Based on what I saw in the code, I tried a couple of variations of:

```
(defaultWebAppSettings root) { ssIndices = map unsafeToPiece ["index.html"],
                               ssRedirectToIndex = True }
```

I'm able to compile and run the server, but I can't get the redirection to work.

Any pointers or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I didn't know about the ssIndices or ssRedirectToIndex settings.  What I did for my app that has dynamic and static parts, was on requests to /, alter that request to say /index.html instead and send it to the "static server".
https://github.com/LeifW/online-typechecker/blob/master/index.hs#L20

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me

```
httpApp :: Wai.Application
httpApp = Static.staticApp $ s {Static.ssIndices = [Static.unsafeToPiece "index.html"]} where s = Static.defaultWebAppSettings "./static"
```